# I only get null as a value in ref after the component unmounts and mounts again

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an auto slider and the problem is that when I click a button that is on the slider and go to other page and then come back to the main page the slider won't run again, also the slides won't be ordered, so nothing will happen, and that is because all is based on useEffect which has a dependencie that won't update again for some reason, so it always stays at null. But if I refresh the page everything works fine, and if I log the ref initially is null, but after it gets updated the element appears (the effect ran a second time).

This is some of the code:

-I have the ref:

`const slidesRef = useRef(null);`

-I create a map to store dom elements in it :

```
  const getSlidesMap = () => {
    if (!slidesRef.current) {
      slidesRef.current = new Map();
    }

    return slidesRef.current;
  };
```

-I have the function that creates the slides and in which returned elements I use the ref:

```
 function createSlides() {
    if (games.length === 0) return;
    const sliderImgs = games.map((game, i) => {
      const gameUrl = game.imgUrl;
      const gameId = game.id;
      return (
        <figure
          key={gameId}
          ref={(slide) => {
            const map = getSlidesMap();

            if (slide) {
              map.set(i, slide);
            }
          }}
          data-gameid={gameId}
          className="gaming__feature-img-container"
        >
          <img
            alt="game"
            src={gameUrl}
            className="gaming__feature-slider-img"
          />
        </figure>
      );
    });
    return sliderImgs;
  }
```

the createSlides function is called when I return the "dom" elements from the component;

-This is a function to check if the elements are there in the ref:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(slidesRef.current);
  }, [slidesRef.current]);
```

I don't know why slidesRef.current is null on the first run of the effect and why it keeps being like that if the component unmounts and then mounts again after I leave that slider page and then come back to it.